# Как сделать "акуратное" экстренное завершение работы?

Tags: исключения

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы когда "вылетала" программа, то заранее появлялось окно для сохранения текущего процесса программы, ну пусть на пример у нас будет массив байт и когда программа страшно повиснет, то мы могли сохранить этот массив?

Такую фичу я наблюдал вроде-бы в Adobe'овских программах, если быть точнее, то в After Effects и ещё в 3Ds max'е 2017 года выпуска.

Comment: чтобы обработать исключения, нужно как обычно обернуть в try catch. Ежели вы говорите о "повисаниях", то это другой вопрос, т.к программа не завершает работу, она вся в работе, что даже сил не остается обработать контролы окна:)

Comment: @tcpack4 блин вот я не знаю, какого рода происходит падение программ (которые я перечислил), если какая нибудь функция что то сделала не правильно то это ладно, как по старинке, как вы и сказали, а вот когда принудительное "не отвечает" из-за какой нибудь подключаемой dll, то вы тоже думаете что try и catch успеет сработать?

Comment: в windows можно перехватить через WinAPI "Программа выполнила некорректное обращение к памяти и будет закрыта" http://www.gamedev.ru/tip/?id=3741 и повесить обработку на обычное закрытие программы (т.е когда программа повисла, через некоторое время система спрашивает не закрыть ли программу) - ProcessExit. Под другие ОС - там по-другому.

Comment: @tcpack4 круто чисто в точку, спасибо, а теперь оформите красиво как ответ, пж )))

Comment: @tcpack4 ну пишите ответ, я проголосую, чтобы вопрос не висел, как не решённый